# LEI Virtual field activity - Locks the sysbase database

Tags: lotus-notes, sybase, lotus-domino

We have multiple virtual activity enabled in our Lotus notes LEI server.

All the connections are between Lotus notes form and Sybase table.

Note: the LEI connection category is ODBC not sybase connection.

Both are using the same user id and password of the Sybase server.

It is happening in rare situation, not often, but monthly once atleast.

The problem is, 
From lotus notes form we have customized error handler. It is throwing Timed out error. Network operation could not be completed. Hope everyone familiar with this error message. I do not see any error log on LEI activity as well as lotus notes server log.

But in the Sybase system's server log, we can see multiple sessions are opened and one of those sessions are in Lock Sleep state.

Whenever this issue comes, we need to restart the sybase server. till it has been restarted we can not access lotus notes database as well.

Please suggest me, how to resolve this issue without restarting the Sybase server. If the connection terminated abnormally from sybase, is their any way to close the LEI activity automatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you can't kill the processes?  Sounds like there is contention over some of the tables, and they end up in a deadlock.  Killing one of the processes should free up the resources necessary to clear the deadlock.

Comment: For me both are same, Im a lotus notes developer, if I ask db team to kill the process I need to have too many communications why? What? Where? How? Etc., :P so I need a permanent solution either from lotus notes or sybase, thanks for your input

Comment: Okay will see what will happen if the same issue comes again... But it seems below solution will work

Comment: Db team can not kill the lock sleep processes. System is not allowing them to kill.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Hopefully the locking scheme changes will resolve the issue.

Comment: Don't kill the lock sleep process - kill the process that is blocking it.  Then the blocked one will run.  This isn't a deadlock but just locking.  Then - what is the process that is blocking other process(es)?  Can you identify it?  You might need Lotus support to help you if you don't know what it is.  You could do an sp_showplan on its spid (you need the DBAs for this, or use Rob Verschoor's method to provide this SP to non-DBAs.)  That showplan will perhaps show a bad queryplan, but the things it is accessing might also tell you whats wrong.  DBAs could DBCC the spid to find the sql too.

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening regularly, then it's probably due to the processes trying tripping over each other and causing a deadlock.

Since you can't really change the application logic, you may need to look at changing the locking scheme/granularity on the Sybase DB.

For more information on locking schemes, check out this [Q/A on Sybase ASE Locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705395/what-is-the-locking-schema-of-sybase-used-for/)